# Apply Material UI component styles to my Custom Component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I built a Rich Text Editor for my react application using Draft.js.
I want to apply the default Material UI TextField styling to this component that I have developed. How can I achieve this?

```html
<>
      <Box
        onClick={() => {
          editorRef.current!.focus();
        }}
        sx={} // What should I add here to get default MUI TextField styles (outlined variant)
      >
        <Editor
          editorKey={`content-text-field-${editorKey}`}
          editorState={editorState}
          onChange={onChange}
          plugins={editorPlugins}
          ref={editorRef}
        />

        <TagSuggestions suggestionsComponent={suggestionsComponent} />
      </Box>

      <TextFieldRoot variant="outlined" />
  </>
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386399/only-use-the-css-of-material-ui-react-components